# Problema creando DialogFragment y llamándolo

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog-fragment

Estoy creando simplemente un DialogFragment con dos botones, que de momento solo quiero que muestren un Toast concreto en cada botón. Este Dialog aparece cuando haces click en un botón dentro de un Activity concreto.

El código en principio, no me da ningún error, pero si le doy al botón la app se detiene y me lanza un error en el Logcat.

Antes de esto, intenté hacer un XML específico para el diseño de este DialogFragment, pero tampoco funcionó.

La documentación de google y otros tutoriales tampoco me dan más pistas sobre cómo corregirlo.

AppCompat no sé exactamente a qué refiere o debo cambiar

```java
public class Config extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btncanc;
    Button btnreestab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_config);
        btncanc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncnacelset);
        btnreestab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrest);

        btncanc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Operación cancelada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                Config.this.finish();
            }
        });
        btnreestab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

                builder.setMessage("Hola");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("cancela", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"adios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

el logcat arroja esto: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 24362 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: Solo cambia el contexto del `new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());` por el de la Actividad quedaria asi: `new AlertDialog.Builder(Config.this);`

Comment: ¡Funciona! muchísimas gracias, ¿sabes cómo podría sustituirlo por uno custom? _uno que dependa de un archivo xml, vaya_ ¿o es mucho más complicado?

Comment: Claro que se puede tendrias que crear un .xml que contendra el diseño de tu dialogo e inflarlo despues, te dejo un ejemplo por si gusta revisarlo : [Custom Dialog](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: pues muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estas lanzando el alert demasiado pronto, lo que debes hacer es pasarle la clase de tu actividad 
Y estas creando un AlertDialog no un DialogFragment

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Config.this);

            builder.setMessage("Hola");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Config.this,"hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancela", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Config.this,"adios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: Vaya, no me había dado cuenta que era un AlertDialog (y que este difiere del DialogFragment)... es la primera vez que uso ambos y no tenía idea. Gracias igualmente, voy a intentar crear un DialogFragment